# How to evaluate the infinite sequence of 0^(-1)^(-2)^(-3)^(-4)^{.}^{.}^{.}?

Tags: limits, infinity, infinite-product, power-towers

(Note: I deliberately didn't write the title in Latex because the notation doesn't display properly with power towers. Specifically regarding the ellipsis, which displays as "..." instead of ".^{.}^{.}", and has caused confusion in past questions)

[image]

This might become a little confusing without the use of latex so what I'm going to do is define $n$ (where $n \in \mathbb{N}$) to equal the number of exponents in the sequence, so that when $n=1$, the sequence is $0^{(-1)}$. When $n=2$, the sequence is $0^{{(-1)}^{(-2)}}$ and so on.

At first I thought this would be a rather easy to answer and trivial question; any continuation of the sequence past $n=1$ should result in an answer equal to zero, which I tried to verify using Wolfram Alpha but it turns out to not be the case. In actuality the value of the sequence for varying values of $n$ is as follows;

$$n=1, \text{value } = \infty$$
$$n=2, \text{value } = 0$$
$$n=3, \text{value } = 0$$
$$n=4, \text{value } = \infty$$
$$n=5, \text{value } = 0$$
$$n=6, \text{value } = 0$$
$$n=7, \text{value } = \infty$$

...and so on. The alternating pattern in the values is particularly interesting, and has me wondering what the value will end up being as $n \to \infty$

Comment: You don't have clear definitions here ( $0^{-1}$ is not really "infinity"). But in general when you have a periodic sequence like that we often say that there's no limit as $n\rightarrow\infty$ or that the sequence diverges

Comment: This does not seem a profitable line to pursue. If $x>1$ then $(x^{-n})^{-n-1}=x^{n^2+n}\ge x^2$. If $0<x<1$ then $x^{-n}>1$. So with a starting positive value of $x\ne1$ we get a divergent sequence. In the case $x=0$ the sequence oscillates between 0 and $\infty$. The case $x=1$ gives a sequence which is always 1. .